# Migrate Specific File could not be copied to

Tags: 8, migrations

I am struggling to get migrate to import images. I have a yml migration that says:

```
[error]  The specified file 'modules/custom/custom_migrate/assets/photos/' could not be copied to 'public://photos//photos'.
```

All the folders are 777. Just to try to eliminate any permissions. I cannot find anything that helps me figure out why. The tmp file is in the sites/default/files/tmp and 777. The folder where the images are is 777 and folders up to that folder are 777. I have searched and tried multiple little things and still no go.

Here is the yml file:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - file
id: photo
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: null
label: Photos
source:
  constants:
    source_base_path: modules/custom/custom_migrate/assets/photos
    uri_file: 'public://photos'
  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: modules/custom/custom_migrate/assets/csv/profile.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - photo
  fields:
    5:
      name: photo
      label: Photo
process:
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - name
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri_file:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/uri_file
        - name
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  filename: name
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@source_full_path'
      - '@uri_file'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

EDIT: Adding the Other yml file, hoping y'all can help me figure where the issue is coming from...

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - migrate_source_csv
id: profile
migration_tags:
  - CSV
migration_group: null
label: Profile
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: modules/custom/custom_migrate/assets/csv/profile.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - id
  #column)names:
  #  0:
  #    name: image_file
  #    label: Image file
    
  #keys:
  #  - id
  fields:
    0:
      name: id
      label: ID
    1:
      name: first_name
      label: First Name
    2:
      name: last_name
      label: Last Name
    3:
      name: birthday
      label: Birthday
    4:
      name: email
      label: Email
    5:
      name: photo
      label: Photo
    6:
      name: languages
      label: Language
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: profile
  title:
    plugin: concat
    source:
      - first_name
      - last_name
    delimiter: ' '
  field_first_name: first_name
  field_last_name: last_name
  field_birthday: birthday
  field_email: email
  field_language:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: languages
  field_photo:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: photo
      delimiter: ;
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: trim
    -
      plugin: callback
      callable: strtoupper
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: photo
      no_stub: true
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  optional:
    - photo
```

Comment: There's probably a mistake somewhere, I think you want to migrate your files in `public://photos` but the error says something about `public://photos//photos`... Maybe something around the `plugin: concat` in the `uri_file`. If you create a `photos` directory in your `public://photos` it might works with the actual yml. Else you gonna have to correct your yml file.

Comment: MAcSim, Thanks for looking it over. I am attaching the other yml file. There is no /photos/photos in either file. I guess I am unsure of how the second /photos got in there. If you can look at the other yml and share any insight. I am still trying to learn this and the error doesn't really help me if it is not in the file. Many thanks!!!

Comment: So, I tweaked the uri_file source and now it just fails saying - Could not create or write to directory ''  The directories are all 777. Any thoughts?